# How do I restore the Visual Studio Code editor to accept Flutter again?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I’m using https://flutter.dev/learn to learn Flutter and Visual Studio Code (VS Code) editor. After successfully completing the exercise, “Your first Flutter app” (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#0), I had started experimenting with the code to better understand both Flutter and VS Code in which I somehow made VS Code to no longer recognize Flutter.

Is there a way to restore VS Code to recognize Flutter once again? See screenshots for context, which is just some basic Flutter code to show what errors I'm getting.

[VS Code full window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpfIi.png)

[Flutter Code with red underlines indicating errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYTBF.png)

[Flutter error messages in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6og5f.png)

I tried,

- the little yellow lightbulb icons that allows to create various classes, such as "StatelessWidget."
- uninstalling and reinstalling the VS Code editor and the extensions Dart and Flutter.
- deleting the folders with my "student" apps.

I expected clicking on the help yellow lightbulb icons would resolve my issue, and when that didn't happen, I tried reinstalling VS Code hoping that would allow me to start over again like the first time around where VS Code had no problem recognizing Flutter. Except after the reinstallation, it was like VS Code was stuck in the state before I uninstalled it and not revert to its original state when I first installed VS Code. To say the least I'm a bit flustered with Flutter and more than vexed with VS Code.

Comment: do you get any issue on `flutter doctor`? also you can try `flutter upgrade -f`

Comment: Flutter Doctor shows issues in 2 categories:

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

Comment: And the second category has to do with C++, which I think was there before and didn't affect Flutter.

Comment: can you try to upgrade/resintall the flutter, then restart the computer

Comment: How do you reinstall flutter? I ask because I thought I had removed and reinstalled Flutter by uninstalling and reinstalling the Flutter extension in VS Code.